# How to solve: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a project structure with mostly empty python files:

```
-project
  --work1
      --__init__.py
      --app.py
      --momo.py
```

momo.py

```
import numpy as np
def plus(x):
    return x
```

app.py

```
from . import momo
a = momo.plus(6)
```

Running app.py directly results in this error:

```
from . import momo
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I have tried change to "from plus import momo" but this yields the same error.

Python version 3.8

Any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package :(](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63312692/importerror-attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package)

Comment: @YashvanderBamel no, it is different

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't import like you said.

you can just try this:

```
import momo
```

it should add `momo` to your current file.

and for using functions which has been declared in `momo`, you should call the function name after `momo.`. for example:

```
a = momo.plus(12)
```

if you just want to import ``` plus`` from ``` momo``` file, you can try

```
from momo import plus
```

then you just need to call function name, instead of the whole file and functions together. e.g :

```
a = plus(12)
```

Comment: I can't just import momo or from momo import plus. It can't include in main.py

Comment: But what error are you getting or why are you unable to do `import momo` inside `app.py`, plus I don't see any `main.py`

Comment: @Tawan where is the ```main.py``` file? can you add the main directory in the post?

Answer (score 0):

Try running it from `project` directory as module (-m flag):

```sh
$ cd project
$ python -m work1.app
```

because when you're starting app directly like `python app.py`, is doesn't know that current folder is actually a package with `__init__.py`
but dot in `from . import *` is a shortcut for a current package.