# Why can't python import a module I created?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I basically want to import the function `videotoimage` from the file `videotoimage.py`.
When I import the function `videotoimage` (inside `videotoimage.py)` from `main.py` by:

```py
from preprocessing.videotoimage import *

videotoimage(dir = "C:\\Users\\{user}\\Desktop\\Deepfake Datasets\\test")
```

I get an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\{user}\Desktop\deepfakedetectML\preprocessing\main.py", line 20, in <module>
    from preprocessing.videotoimage import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'preprocessing'
```

The project tree is:

```
C:.
│   CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
│   LICENSE
│   README.md
│   requirements.txt
│
├───.github
│   │   CODEOWNERS
│   │
│   └───ISSUE_TEMPLATE
│           bug_report.yml
│           documentation.yml
│           feature_request.yml
│
└───preprocessing
        extractfaces.py
        main.py
        videotoimage.py
```

The code inside videotoimage.py is: https://privatebin.net/?9c10407fd482752d#AHcNVb12VjquQJEmdJKZEmor8amAGuAkVp3HNhnKHSHC

Comment: Your script is in the same folder as videotoimage.py. Just `import videotoimage`

Comment: which python version are you using? If i remember correctly, in older versions is was necessary to place a `__init__.py` into `preprocessing` in order to `import preprocessing.videotoimage` from withing a module in `preprocessing`.

Comment: Do you have a `__init__.py` in your `preprocessing` module? See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for information on packaging and modules.

Comment: `main.py` and `videotoimage.py` are in the same folder so you can do `from videotoimage` . To use `from preprocessing.videotoimage` you would have to add `c:\Users\{user}\Desktop\deepfakedetectML` to `sys.path` before importing

Comment: You may wish to follow a packaging tutorial (such as [this one](https://python-packaging-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup_py.html), with the use of a `setup.py` file) to turn your project into a proper python package so you can actually name your top level import `preprocessing`.

Comment: @H.Doebler, I'm using Python 3.9.6

Comment: @AmithLakkakula, I tried it, I get a `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: @Alex, I tried following your steps and made an `__init__.py` with the neccessary imports inside it, but it didn't fix anything, I got the same error

Comment: @user69420 the `__init__.py` should be empty

Comment: @furas, I'm not trying to make a python library, I'm just trying to import stuff

Comment: @Alex, I tried the selected solution and it fixed everything. anyway thanks for your help

Comment: I think with an `__init__.py` he can `import preprocessing.videotoimage` only from a module next to the `preprocessing` directory. Within that directory such imports are only possible if `preprocessing` is an installed package (eg in a venv using `pip install . -e`). Or using `sys.path` tweaking, but you certainly dont want to do that.

Comment: it doesn't matter if you create module or not. if `main.py` and `videotoimage.py` are in the same folder then you should use `from videotoimage`. Method with `sys.path` will be useful when you will have to run code from different folder (different `Current Working Director` - `os.getcwd()`) - like. `python c:\preprocessing\main.py` because then it will search `videotoimage` in different folder and you will need something like `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` to get folder with code - and add it to `sys.path` before importing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preprocessing is not a package in your tree. Either you can make it a package by inserting an `__init__.py` file, or you can just call it relatively:

```
from videotoimage import *
```

Comment: Or even better: make the relative import explicit by using `from .videotoimage import *`. If `from <...> import *` is considered 'good' at all, but thats a different question.

Comment: Good suggestion, added it to the answer.

Comment: I tried the previous solution, `from videotoimage import *` and it worked, however, your updated answer doesn't work, it gives an `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Forgot that you did not already had a `__init__.py`. Anyway, you should go that way, because it avoids name clashes if you happen to install a package called `videotoimage` in the future.

Comment: True, but for the sake of simplicity of this question, the import without the dot will work. Also see the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63312776/16689404

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
from videotoimage import *
```