# import functions in file from parent directory python

Tags: python

If I have the following directory structure:

```
Folder1/  
└─ Folder2/  
   ├─ a.py  
   └─ Subfolder2/  
      └─ b.py
```

Folder2/a.py contains some functions.

I want to import a function in **b.py** from another file(**a.py**) in the parent directory(**Folder2**).

Can you help me figure out how my child file can successfully import functions in a.py to b.py

I tried

```
from .Folder2 import a
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package :(](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63312692/importerror-attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package)

Comment: Have you had a look at any of the answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) or other questions about relative imports?

Comment: Yes, i did it but i didint find an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following statement:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), ".."))
import a
```

The function `sys.path.insert()` will allow you to import python files from the defined path.

see [doc](https://pymotw.com/2/sys/imports.html) for more information

Comment: I want to import functions inside the file a.py and i still get function is not defined

Comment: With functions do you mean other python files or modules? If you mean python files, where is the location of them?

Answer (score 0):

#### Solving this problem without relative imports and without using sys.path:

Folder Structure:

```bash
root/
   serve/
       - app.py
   src/
       - utils.py
```

To access functions of utils.py in app.py, use:
`from src.utils import function`

Running from root:
`python -m serve.app`

[instead of `python serve/app.py`]

`-m mod` allows to run library module as a script.