# Python ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, python-import, fastapi

I'm learning [fastapi](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/). I have a very simple project structure like this

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── database.py
├── main.py
├── models.py
├── requirements.txt
└── schemas.py
```

Inside `main.py` is

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from typing import Optional
from . import schemas, models
from .database import engine

app = FastAPI()

# more code here...
```

but when I run this with `uvicorn main:app --reload` I get the error

> ...
> from . import schemas, models
> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. I'm loosely following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/7t2alSnE2-I?t=5485). I've also read through numerous related SO questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084977/attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63312692/importerror-attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package)), but none seem to match my situation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing the files as "from . import schemas, models", Try importing it directly like this - **import schemas,models**.I think this might work.

Comment: This worked, thanks! But why did `from . import schemas, models` not work?

Answer (score 0):

Although your logic of "." directory is right, relative imports always relay on environment configurations, which may vary depending by IDE, venv and such stuffs, E.G. the `env` may vary at runtime in VScode based on the `launch.json` and `settings.json`

**I'd suggest you to better structure your project so that it contains package folders containing the `__init__.py` and the homonym module name, thus you can setup the import behave in the `__init__.py` file.**

Exempli Gratia: Here `Database`, `Model1` and `Model2` are classes in the `database/database.py` and `models/models.py`[image]

Where `database/__init__.py` is defined as follows to link the Database class inside database.py the import at the "upper" folder
[image]

And the `models/__init__py` similarly links `models.py` classes to the "upper" folder
[image]

#### Notice how referring to directories with the `from` keyword uses the `__init__.py` inside the called directory *by default* to import objects to main, thus you could define specific instances or variables along with constants directly into the `__init__.py` at will along with any kind of operation (although is not always a good thing to do...)