# Add module to self defined function

Tags: python, import, pytorch, package, yolo

I am building a yolo model using pytorch, but I would like to build an activation function by myself.

I need to import `module.py` to my own function. So I write `from .modules import Module` and run. It returns me `attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

This is the file location of my yolo:

`C:/Users/Lenovo/.spyder-py3/yolo.py`

This is the file location of the module.py that I want to call:

`C:/Users/Lenovo/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py`

I have tried to rewrite the import statement as below:

`__import__("C:/Users/Lenovo/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py").Module`

It also returns me the same import error. My understanding is that because in the `module.py`, there is an import statement `from ..parameter import Parameter`, where the `..` refers the `module.py` to `C:/Users/Lenovo` (instead of `C:/Users/Lenovo/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/torch/nn`).

My question is, what should I do to import the `Module` and use it in `yolo.py` for my own use, without having import error?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63312692/importerror-attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package) may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it really helps me a lot. Seems that I can only do that with a shared package... or I have to create one extra python files in that package for my own use.